# How to concisely select elements in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I love the jQuery syntax of `$('mySelector')`. It's short, neat, and powerful. But I don't want to include jQuery in my pages. I want jQuery's `$` selector function as part of native JS.

I know I can use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`, but the first problem is these are verbose-- I don't want to write `document.querySelectorAll('mySelector')` everytime, it just bloats the code far too much.

I could shorten it by using a line like this~

> var $ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);

Then I would have the `$`, but it still wouldn't work well, since it would be returning arrays and I would have to be checking the array length and either indexing elements out of the array or else using `forEach` every time, further bloating the code.

How can I concisely and effectively select elements in pure modern JavaScript ?

Comment: Are you taking about selecting elements with specific classes? Any example please.

Comment: These are two questions: how to alias document.querySelector[All] and how to concisely perform actions on the returned element groups. I think you've solved the former. The latter probably involves using some newer functional-style JavaScript features.

Comment: jQuery selector syntax does not solve the problem of having to iterate the elements. It still returns an array-like object.

Comment: Almost always if you find yourself doing the same things repeatedly the answer is either find a function or make a function that does those things (call it '$' if you want).

Comment: What is the reason why you what the jQuery functionality but you don't want to use jQuery? If you want to keep the footprint small, and you don't need all functions of jQuery then you can always create a custom build, that contains only certain modules. E.g. only `css`  and `events`  without `ajax` , `animation` ,  ...

Comment: @t.niese how do you create a custom build of jQuery? Seems tedious.

Comment: @Aerovistae [jQuery: Modules](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#modules) describes how to do that with grunt. (e.g.`grunt custom:-ajax,-sizzle,-offset,-effects,-dimensions,-deprecated,-warp`), but afaik you currently can remove the dom traversing functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the very small selector libraries at http://microjs.com/#selector

Query - https://github.com/ded/qwery
and balalaika - https://github.com/finom/balalaika seems to be very applicable for use.

You may also want to check Sizzle (https://github.com/jquery/sizzle).

Although, I would recommend using plain `querySelectorAll` to do the processing. It's a lot faster and doesn't really bloat the code a lot.

```
const $ = sel => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(sel));
$('.selector').forEach(el => {});
```

I generally create three helper functions:

```
$ = sel => document.querySelector(sel) // single element
$id = id => document.getElementById(id)
$$ = sel => [...document.querySelectorAll(sel)]; // multiple elements
```

Also, if I need a deeper or more complex selection, I make use of `filter` or `find` like:

```
$$(sel).filter(el => el.innerText === "mytext");
// similar to what jQuery contains would do
```

You should also check out "You don't need jQuery" for many other such tricks and functions. Vanilla js is as much powerful as any library built on it.

You'll most likely end up with creating your own selector libraries/helper functions. So, better use some lightweight selector libraries, like mentioned above.

Comment: `sizzle`  uses `querySelectorAll` whenever possible. It only falls back to its own code the query is not selected by the browser, or if the browser has a known bug for the given query. So if the query is supported by the browser using sizzle should not be noticeable slower then `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Agreed. But it is still has one extra level of indirection. But not really slow in general applications.

Comment: What is the advantage of `$$ = sel => [...document.querySelectorAll(sel)];` over `$$ = sel => document.querySelectorAll(sel);` ?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`. With `[...]`, we convert it to an array. We can use Array methods like `map`, `filter`, `find` easily then. Not always needed, but has it's own use cases :)

Comment: For any future readers, I ended up using Sudhanshu's approach here, with my own slight modification. For `$$`, I use this: `var $$ = function(selector, f) {
 let elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
 if (f && typeof f === 'function') {
  elements.forEach(f);
 }
 return [...elements];
};` It lets me avoid having to write out `forEach` every time I use `$$`.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is essentially a wrapper object for NodeList which adds more functionality to DOM operations. If you want to create your own wrapper object which defines functions for bulk versions of all the Element API, you are free to do so, but then you might as well use jQuery or some derivative.

If you want an extremely lightweight proxy object for doing bulk operations on DOM elements, there is the Proxy object in ES6 which can make this very easy to do.

The Proxy object is used to define custom behavior for fundamental operations (e.g. property lookup, assignment, enumeration, function invocation, etc).

**Note:** The Proxy object has no IE support.

```js
// select a list of matching elements, context is optional

const $ = function( selector, context ) {
    const nodeList = (context || document).querySelectorAll( selector );

    return new Proxy( nodeList, {
        set: function( target, property, value ) {
            for ( let i = 0; i < target.length; i++ ) {
                target[ i ][ property ] = value;
            }
        },
        get: function( target, property ) {
            return target[ 0 ] && target[ 0 ][ property ];
        }
    });
};

function test() {
  $( '.myclass' ).innerHTML = '<a href="#">New HTML</a>';
  $( '.myclass' ).className = 'redcolor';
  $( 'p' ).innerHTML = 'Click the links for check Binding of event handlers';

  $( 'a' ).onclick = function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log( 'a tag Clicked!' )
  }
}
```

```css
.redcolor {
    color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">Element 1</div>
<div class="myclass">Element 2</div>
<div class="myclass">Element 3</div>
<div class="myclass">Element 4</div>
<div class="myclass">Element 5</div>

<button type="button" onclick="test()">Test</button>
<p></p>
```

By doing so, you can use $(...) to fetch elements just like you would with jQuery; you can even pass in a context element.

Comment: Can you expand the code example slightly to include how you could use `Proxy` to also access the methods on DOM nodes, like `addEventListener` ? Or can it only be used for get/setting properties?

Comment: Sorry, the edit you made still shows a property being set, not a method being called-- you're setting the value of the `onclick` property. I would like to be able to do `$('a').addEventListener(...)`.